# can you set a string to a macro

Tags: c, colors, header, macros, ansi-c

I am trying to get a user to enter a colour and the output will be the sentence in the chosen colour
I am using ansi escape codes set as variable, and im not sure on how to work the last one

```
#define red "\033[1;31m"
#define green "\033[0;32m"
#define blue "\033[0;34m"
#define magenta "\033[0;35m"
#define yellow "\033[0;33m"
#define cyan "\033[0;36m"

  int main() 
  {
        char colour1[10];

        printf("enter a colour");
        scanf("%s", colour1);

        
        printf("%s this is test\n ", red);
        printf("%s another test \n", green);
        printf("%s hello test ", colour1);

        return 0;
}
```

so say if the user was to enter "blue" it would just output the word blue and not the colour ,
thank you
any help would be mutely appreciated

Comment: Macros in C is compile-time string replacement, so it won't affect at runtime. You should create a table and a code to lookup the table.

Comment: If the user types `garble`, `printf("%s hello test ", colour1)` will print `garble hello test`. Now if the user types `blue`, why should `printf("%s hello test ", colour1)` print something else than `blue hello test` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your seem to have a confused understanding of macros. Macro substitution is performed by the pre-processor and this is one-step before the actual compilation. Hence macro substitution can never be performed on user input which does not come in until the program is compiled and actually run!

Here is an example of a working lookup-table based implementation suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64006688/can-you-set-a-string-to-a-macro#comment113184065_64006688).

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct colortable_t
{
  char* name;
  char* code;
} colortable_t;

const colortable_t colortable[] = 
{
  { "red", "\033[1;31m" },
  { "green", "\033[0;32m" },
  { "blue", "\033[0;34m" },
  { "magenta", "\033[0;35m" },
  { "yellow", "\033[0;33m" },
  { "cyan", "\033[0;36m" },
};

const char *color_lookup(const char *str)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(colortable) / sizeof(colortable_t); i++)
  {
    if(strcmp(colortable[i].name, str) == 0)
      return colortable[i].code;
  }
  return "";
}

int main() 
{
  char colour1[10];

  printf("enter a colour");
  scanf("%s", colour1);

  printf("%s this is test\n ", color_lookup("red"));
  printf("%s another test \n", color_lookup("green"));
  printf("%s hello test ", color_lookup(colour1));

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you store the string the user entered in `colour1` wich is "blue" or "red" your `printf` will substitute this to "blue hello test". However what you want is something like "\033[0;34m hello test". For this you need to map the input of the user to your color defines somehow.

This could look like this:

```
//mapping and setting colour
if( 0 == strcmp(colour1, "blue") ) {
   printf( %s, blue );
} else if ( 0 == strcmp(colour1, "red") ) {
   printf( %s, red);
} else if (...) {
  ...
}

//printing your text
printf( "hello test\n" );
```

C is not very nice with strings and I guess there are a bunch of other ways to map the input of the user to the color, however this should give you the expected result. It would probably be a bit nicer to implement a lookup table, as others mentioned, to not have the if else as i am showing here, however the concept of mapping your defines to the input stays the same.